# How to create a new variable that links matching rows under specific criteria in a dataset

Tags: r, loops

Let's say I have a dataset like this one:

```
df <- 
  data.frame(var1 = rep(LETTERS[1:3],
                        each = 4), 
             var2 = rep(LETTERS[4:6], 
                        each = 2), 
             var3 = c('F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'G'), 
             var4 = c('H', 'H', 'I', 'I', 'L', 'L'), 
             var5 = c('M', 'N', 'O', 'N', 'M', 'P', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'N', 'M', 'N'), 
             var6 = c('x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y'), 
             var7 = c('', '', '', '', '', ''))
```

and I want to fill up the column called "var7" accordingly to the following criteria:

1. Group by var1 AND var2 AND var3 AND var4. Then compare each pair of rows. If both var5 and var6 are different between the two rows, it is a match and thus assign a same unique var7 value to the two compared rows (they are now linked).
2. If a row has more then one match (e.g., a row matches with two other rows that have different var5 value), then duplicate the row and assign a unique var7 value to each of them and the corresponding match.
3. If two rows have **different** var1 OR var2 OR var3 OR var4 OR **same** var6, do not do anything (no match).

Thus, I want to create a loop that compare each row with any row in the data table.
Each decision of the loop ends assigning a new unique var7 value to the two rows OR doing nothing.
Each row will have at least one matching row.

At the end, in this case and if the loop worked, I will have this result:

```
df2 <- 
  data.frame(var1 = rep(LETTERS[1:3],
                        each = 4), 
             var2 = rep(LETTERS[4:6],
                        each = 2), 
             var3 = c('F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'G'), 
             var4 = c('H', 'H', 'I', 'I', 'L', 'L'), 
             var5 = c('M', 'N', 'O', 'N', 'M', 'P', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'N', 'M', 'N'),
             var6 = c('x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y'), 
             var7 = c('1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '4', '4', '5', '5', '6', '6'))
```

Note: in this case I do not have duplicated rows where the only difference between them is the var7 value because noone of the rows has more than one match.

I am thinking of using dplyr::group_by() to group by var1:var5. However, I do not know how to ask R to iterate each row following my three istructions reported above.

Thanks in advance to anyone will kindly reply and apologize if I did not explain my self at its best.